# display screen of "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $!;"

Tags: php, linux, exec

I'm running a task over linux command line (with PHP exec_shell command). This script is displaying its progression and results at standard screen when it is ran normally.

I added `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $!;` so the task can run in background and to not block PHP script execution.

after several minutes of running, i see that the processus is still live (htop, ps commands), but the data is not updated anymore. I guess that something went wrong and the script was stopped/pended but not killed.

what I want to know is if is there a way to see the logs of my script as I have its main PID (returned by my PHP when ran). May be I can find somewhere the output of my script ?

Thanks

Comment: "May be I can find somewhere the output of my script ?"  Not if you're redirecting the output to /dev/null.  It might be good to research what `> /dev/null` does.

Comment: thanks @Devon, I know what >dev/null do :). I wonder if is there a way to find all pending task (crashed bu PID not killed) ?

Comment: Have you looked at top ?

Comment: @GemTaylor htop gives me a running pid

Comment: top shows zombies as well. Zombies are waiting for their parent top check their return code. Then it is gone. When it is gone it is gone.

Comment: I think your program is probably not crashed if top does not say it is stopped or zombie. Your program could be waiting for input, or gone into a broken loop processing the data. Can you attach a debugger to the process `gdb --pid xxxx`